# JavaScript finding matching values in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, matching

The array is sorted in an increasing order and I would like to get the values of the matching ones separated by a colon.

```
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5];
var text = "";

for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    if(array[0] == array[0 + 1]) {
         text = array[0] + ":" + array[0 + 1]; // 1:1
    }
}
```

This for-loop only checks for two matching values. How would I check for all the number of matching values?

So for 1, the text would be 1:1
for 2, the text would be 2:2:2
for 5, the text would be 5:5:5:5

Comment: you will need to nest a loop

Comment: i don't quite get what you want to achieve. why do you store everything in the same text variable? if you just want to print out the array as text there are easier ways. If you want to store each number text e.g. in an array, this sounds like a Array.reduce() job

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
var text = ''

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i + 1]) {
         // always add a : suffix
         text += array[i] + ':'; 
    } else {
         // replace the last character with the last value and a new line
         text = text.replace(/.$/, ':' + array[i] + '\n')
    }
}

console.log(text.trim()) // trim the trailing whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
arrayLength = array.length,
text = {};


for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if(!text.hasOwnProperty(array[i])){
      text[array[i]] = []
      for(var e = 0; e < arrayLength; e++){
          if(array[i] == array[e]){
            text[array[i]].push(array[i])
          }
      }
      text[array[i]] = text[array[i]].join(':')
    }
}



//and now you can access to every string by text[number]

for(var key in text){
    console.log(text[key])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. I hope this does what you're looking for.

```js
const 
  input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  // Based on the input create a set, each value will appear only once in 
  // the set.
  uniqueIds = new Set(input),
  result = [];

// Iterate over all the unique values of the array.
uniqueIds.forEach(id => {
  // Add the text for the current value to result array.
  result.push(
    // Filter the array, take only the items that match the current value. This
    // will result in a new array that can be joined using a ":" as a
    // separator character.
    input.filter(value => value === id).join(':')
  );
});


// Or on a single line:
// uniqueIds.forEach(id => result.push(input.filter(value => value === id).join(':')));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to get a string based on an input you provide, perhaps this is better:

```js
const 
  input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  textWrapper = (function() {
    let
      array = null,
      cache = {};
      
    function getText(number) {
      if (cache[number] !== undefined) {
        console.log(`Cache hit for number ${number}`);
        return cache[number];
      }
      
      const
        text = array.filter(item => item === number).join(':');
      cache[number] = text;
      
      return text;
    }
      
    function setArray(value) {
      array = value;
      cache = {};
    }
    
    return {
      getText,
      setArray
    }
  })();
  
textWrapper.setArray(input);

const
  values = [1, 3, 5, 5];
  
values.forEach(value => console.log(`Text for ${value} is "${textWrapper.getText(value)}"`));
```